# Mongoose populate not working upto 3 levels

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to populate a fields that is nested inside my model but it is not populating.

This is a field inside my model.

```
pendingChanges: {
credentials: {
  university: {
    name: { type: String },
    major: { type: String },
    majorGpa: { type: Number },
  },
  school: {
    name: { type: String },
    degreeType: { type: String },
    degree: { type: String },
  },
  subjects: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'subject' }],
  workExperience: {
    type: { type: String },
    from: { type: Date },
    to: { type: Date },
  },
 },
},
```

I am trying to populate subjects key nested inside.

This is what I have done so far.

```
const teacher = (await this.findById(id))
    .populate({
      path: 'pendingChanges',
      populate: {
        path: 'credentials',
        populate: {
          path: 'subjects',
        },
      },
    });
```

Comment: Can you please give us more details about your error ?

Comment: It would be nice if you had given sample documents for all the 4 collections.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Here's what I did to make it work.

```
const data = await this.findOne(query)
    .populate({
      path: 'pendingChanges.credentials.subjects',
    });
```